# How to disable the letter scroll in gridview on Android

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I am new to Android and am trying to use a gridview to display certain data.
The problem is the gridview shows a LetterScroller or Alphabetical scroller at the right of the screen.

I do not have any use of such a scroll and would like to disable it.
Couldn't find anything on this topic.

Also as of now, when i click on the letter Scroller it crashes with the following msg in LOGCAT:

```
04-11 00:59:42.183: E/AndroidRuntime(7154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 00:59:42.183: E/AndroidRuntime(7154): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 00:59:42.183: E/AndroidRuntime(7154):     at android.widget.LetterScroller.scrollTo(LetterScroller.java:233)
04-11 00:59:42.183: E/AndroidRuntime(7154):     at android.widget.LetterScroller.onTouchEvent(LetterScroller.java:304)
04-11 00:59:42.183: E/AndroidRuntime(7154):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3460)
04-11 00:59:42.183: E/AndroidRuntime(7154):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
04-11 00:59:42.183: E/AndroidRuntime(7154):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
```

Comment: the letter scroller came up only on 4.1.2 version and above. It wont show up on all previous versions

Comment: LetterScroller.java:233; NPE anyway.

Comment: I'm not an Android programmer, but does disabling `fastScrollEnabled` help?

Comment: setFastScrollEnabled(false) ?

Comment: i tried disabling it, but it did not help

Comment: well, disabling 'fastScrollEnabled' did not help, but when i enabled the same, it replaced the LetterScroller with the fastScroll and that works fine. Thus i have found an alternative to my problem, but I would really like to know if the LetterScroller can be disabled.